# Something strange about regular expression

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following regular expression code:

```
var str = "{$ for ( var i = 0, len = O.length; i < len; i++ ) { $}";

var reg = /\{\$(.*?)\$\}/g;

console.log(reg.test(str));

console.log(reg.test(str));

console.log(reg.test(str));
```

Why is the result an alternation of True and False?

Comment: Remove global flag and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> When you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string use the test method (similar to the String.search method); for more information (but slower execution) use the exec method (similar to the String.match method). As with exec (or in combination with it), **test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.**

To illustrate what's happening, we can use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and see what's happening. In order of passes:

1. *original string* (truthy)
   The entire string is matched which is evaluated as true.
2. `null` (falsy)
   Consecutive calls continue on, so since the first called returned the entire result, we are left with `null`.
3. *original string* (truthy)
   And the pattern returns back to start and continues on.

For proof, [run the following](http://jsfiddle.net/qHwvS/):

```
var str = '{$ for ( var i = 0, len = O.length; i < len; i++ ) { $}';
var reg = /\{\$(.*?)\$\}/g;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var result = reg.exec(str);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(!!result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript `RegExp`s [maintain state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#RegExp_instances-Properties) internally, including fields such as the last index matched. Because of that, you can see some interesting behavior when reusing a regex as in the example you give.

The `/g` flag would cause it to return `true` once for each successive match against the given string (of which there only happens to be one in your example), after which it would return `false` once and then start all over again. Between each call, the aforementioned `lastIndex` property would be updated accordingly.

Consider the following:

```
var str = "12";
var regex = /\d/g;

console.log(regex.test(str)); // true
console.log(regex.test(str)); // true
console.log(regex.test(str)); // false
```

Versus:

```
console.log(/\d/g.test(str)); // true
console.log(/\d/g.test(str)); // true
console.log(/\d/g.test(str)); // true
console.log(/\d/g.test(str)); // true
// ...and so on, since you're instantiating a new RegExp each time
```